# Please someone please explain me the difference between the below mention functions

Tags: javascript, for-loop

First function

```
function isPrime(num) {
    if(num < 2) return false;
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num%i==0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Second function

```
function isPrime(num) {
    if(num < 2) return false;
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am really not able to wrap my mind around this code..

Comment: In the first case your loop will only run its first iteration and return either false or true, that is it won't work. In the second case it will run through all values and check if it is divisible by every `i` from 2 to `n`, and return `true` if there are no, that's how you calculate is a number is prime (this algorithm is not very efficient though).

Comment: The first function will always exit in the first iteration, since either `return false` or `return true` are executed. The second one will return from the loop only if `num%i==0` is true.

Comment: Here is a simpler example: `function one() { if (false) { return false; } else { return true; } console.log('end'); }` and `function two() { if (false) { return false; } console.log('end'); return true; }`. This is basically your example but without the loop. Note how `one` doesn't log "end" while `two` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one will stop straight after the first iteration, because of the `else` statement. `return` breaks the loop. It will only test if the number you give is even or odd `num%2 == 0`.

The second one will stop only if the condition is verified (again, the return breaks the loop), or at the end of all iterations.

In your example, only the second one gives the expected result:

```js
function isPrimeA(num) {
    if(num < 2) return false;
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num%i==0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}

function isPrimeB(num) {
    if(num < 2) return false;
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

console.log(isPrimeA(15))
console.log(isPrimeB(15))
```